GitHub token and github actions for graphql and push
Context
I'm trying to make some project management automations on a project, linked to a repo (or more later) which seem basic to me, but not implemented in GitHub yet (moving a card to a certain column when a commit mentioning a certain issue is pushed, move to another column when a pull request is open, adding labels automatically, etc.).
To do so, I use:

octokit/graphql-action : As I use projects in an organization, I need access to projectV2, which is not accessible with rest API.
actions/scripts : To process responses of graphql queries or make various things such as multiple mutations in a row.
basic run : for debug OR git actions.

In this context, I need to use a token to access the graphql API.
Current situation
PAT settings in organization

Allow Access via fine-grained personal access token
Do not require administration approval
Fine grained personal access token mustn't expire

General policies of Actions
Allow all actions and reusable workflows
Workflow permission of GITHUB_TOKEN

Read and Write permissions
Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests

PAT settings on my side

Organization permissions

Read access to organization API insights, organization events, and organization plan
Read and Write access to custom organization roles, custom repository roles, members, organization actions variables, organization administration, organization announcement banners, organization codespaces, organization codespaces secrets, organization codespaces settings, organization copilot seat management, organization dependabot secrets, organization hooks, organization knowledge bases, organization secrets, organization self hosted runners, organization user blocking, and team discussions

Read, Write, and Admin access to organization custom properties and organization projects




Repository permissions

Read access to codespaces metadata and metadata
Read and Write access to Dependabot alerts, actions, actions variables, administration, attestations api, code, codespaces, codespaces lifecycle admin, codespaces secrets, commit statuses, dependabot secrets, deployments, discussions, environments, issues, merge queues, pages, pull requests, repository advisories, repository custom properties, repository hooks, secret scanning alerts, secrets, security events, and workflows



My permissions in workflow
permissions: write-all

Problems
1. GraphQL
When I use my PAT token, both in postman and GitHub action, to make queries involving nodes (ex: projectV2), everything works fine ! BUT when I try to do the same thing with the GITHUB_TOKEN, nodes is now and empty list and I can't access to the data I need. No errors, nothing, just an empty list.
here is the query I use:
query ($repo: String!, $organisation: String!) {
    organization(login: $organisation) {
        repository(name: $repo, followRenames: true) {
            projectsV2(first: 100) {
                nodes {
                    id
                    number
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

there is the response to my request via postman
{
    "data": {
        "organization": {
            "repository": {
                "projectsV2": {
                    "nodes": [
                        {
                            "id": "PVT_kwDOCva0384ArM0P",
                            "number": 7
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


and here is the response to the same request via GitHub action when using GITHUB_TOKEN
{
    "organization": {
      "repository": {
        "projectsV2": {
          "nodes": []
        }
      }
    }
  };

WHY?! In the end, I could have just used my PAT token, but I want to understand why it doesn't work with GITHUB_TOKEN... And there is a second problem.
2. Git push.
For... Reasons, I need to push some files to the repo. Tired of pushing for testing, I decided to use act to test my workflow locally... and when I tried, everything worked fine !
But when I tried it with GitHub action... I got the following error:
 ! [remote rejected] setting_update_data -> setting_update_data (refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/data/data.json` without `workflows` permission)
error: failed to push some refs to

no matter the token I try to use: PAT or GITHUB_TOKEN... SAME RESULT. AND I HAVE ALL PERMISSIONS WITH BOTH.
by the way, I can't make pushes with an "anonymous" user, I need to use my own account. (so far)
Concrete code
My requests and scripts are in separated files, but I gave you the only query so far so you have everything you need to understand. (And scripts are not the problem... because they work with the good outputs)
Last precision : the current triggers are push, workflow_dispatch and repository_dispatch. But it will be manual later.
It will be hard for me to cover all different configurations of g token, pat, permissions, etc. so here is the current workflow I'm using, and then I will try your suggestions and give you resuls:
name: Set/Update Datas


on:
  workflow_dispatch: 
  repository_dispatch: 
  push:

permissions: write-all

env:
  organisation: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
  PERSONNAL_TOKEN: "###"
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}

jobs:
  init_setup:
    permissions: write-all    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      need_init: ${{ steps.check_data_file.outputs.need_init }}
      requests: ${{ steps.read_requests.outputs.result }}
      repo: ${{ steps.get_repo_name.outputs.repo }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    
    - name: Check if data file exists
      id: check_data_file
      run: |
        if [ -f .github/workflows/data/data.json ]; then
          echo "::set-output name=need_init::true"
        else
          echo "::set-output name=need_init::false"
        fi

    - name: Check github token
      id: check_github_token
      run: |
        echo "PERSONNAL_TOKEN=${PERSONNAL_TOKEN}"
        echo "GITHUB_TOKEN=${GITHUB_TOKEN}"
    - name: Read Requests
      id: read_requests
      uses: actions/github-script@v7.0.1
      with:
        script: |
          const script = require('./.github/workflows/read_requests.js');

          path = './.github/workflows/manual/';
          return script({path});
    - name: Get Repo Name
      id: get_repo_name
      run: echo "repo=${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#*/}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  
  initialisation_basic_settings:
    permissions: write-all
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [init_setup]
    if : ${{ needs.init_setup.outputs.need_init == 'false' }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Get Project ID and Number
      id: get_project_id_and_number
      uses: octokit/graphql-action@v2.x
      env: 
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ env.PERSONNAL_TOKEN }}
      with:
        query: ${{ fromJson(needs.init_setup.outputs.requests).get_project_id_and_number }}
        variables: |
          {
            "organisation": "${{ env.organisation }}",
            "repo": "${{ needs.init_setup.outputs.repo }}"
          }
  
    - name: Modify first settings
      id: modify_first_settings
      uses: actions/github-script@v7.0.1
      with:
        github-token: ${{ env.PERSONNAL_TOKEN }}
        script: | 
          const script = require('./.github/workflows/write_json.js');
          const path = './.github/workflows/data/data.json';
          const request_response = ${{ steps.get_project_id_and_number.outputs.data }};
          console.log("request_response",JSON.stringify(request_response));
          const node = request_response.organization.repository.projectsV2.nodes[0];
          const settings = {
            project_id: node.id,
            project_number: node.number,
          };
          console.log("settings",settings);
          const json_data = {
            settings: settings
          };
          const data = JSON.stringify(json_data);
          console.log("json_data",json_data);
          script({path, data});
        
    - name: Store first settings
      id: store_first_settings
      env: 
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ env.PERSONNAL_TOKEN }}
      run: |
        git config --local user.name "###"
        git config --local user.email "###"
        git add .
        git commit -m "Set first settings"
        git push


There's a lot in here, but none of it is the github-actions code, and I can't really guess what you're doing wrong without that. What can you share of that? How is it triggered? From where is it triggered?... some of the things I'll be looking for: 1) are you passing the GITHUB_TOKEN to the env.GITHUB_TOKEN for graphql-action (you have to). How are you doing the git push? How are you setting those environment variables for that? To clarify: these are things that need to be answered by the code; show us; don't just answer the questions.

@DanCrews Thanks for your input, I changed my question to include my current workflow file. If you have any suggestions, I would be happy to test it :)
